# COM/COM+ or Windows Communication Foundation (WCF)?

Tags: .net, wcf, com

We are developing a desktop application for Windows using C#. The application does some heavy calculation and drives specialized hardware. Our application should expose some functionality that other third party desktop applications can use out-of-process (i.e. host - client), which includes accessing data that lives in our application, or commanding our application to perform some actions. One of the reasons that we require this capability is to allow automation from third-party applications.

I have been looking into some possibilities to accomplish what we want but this topic is completely new for me so I thought the best would be to ask for advice to people with more experience. So far I have looked into COM/COM+ and Windows Communication Foundation (WCF). Both seem to offer the means to achieve what we need, but:

- COM/COM+ : I know COM have been around for long, and most of the documentation I find is from a few years ago. I have nothing against that, I just wonder whether this is still the recommended way to go.
- Windows Communication Foundation (WCF): I get the impression that WCF is used more in the context of web services and I have seen some concerns about performance when compared to COM (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/adb79021-89b8-47ab-a02d-33b2e777cb73/wcfcom-performance-comparison?forum=wcf)

For the record, I have also look into .Net Remoting, but it is not the recommended approach for new developments (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwdt6w2k(v=vs.100).aspx)

From what I have read, some years ago the solution to this would have been to make our application a COM server. I don't know whether this is still the way to go, or the prefered way nowdays is to use WCF.

What would be your advice on this matter? Is there another approach?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: COM is kind of universal when it comes to classic desktop apps and almost any (Windows) language/technology can use COM (and despite its age COM is still heavily used by Microsoft also for new things such as WinRT/UWP). Are the any restrictions/requirements regarding the third-party tools that you want to support?

Comment: Within the context that I described, we would like to put as little restrictions as possible on the third-party application. I don't think that WCF will impose more restrictions on it that COM, will it?

Comment: When the world is shifting to micro services (for inter-operation) and ASP.NET Web API (or ASP.NET Core), it would be quite interesting to see anyone put COM and WCF on the table. Yes, you can still use COM and WCF but what features are you looking for?

Comment: @LexLi Forgive my ignorance, my knowledge of ASP.net is equal to zero, but I don't see how ASP.net fits in here. Our app is not internet conected or cloud based. It is a clasic desktop application that has to host some services for other desktop applications runing in the same computer. From what I have read, 10-15 years ago this was done using COM, i.e. our application would be a COM host, but I don't know whether now days WCF is prefered. Ill edit the question to clarify this.

Comment: @sinad So much has changed, and it would be impossible to describe all in a few words. Thus, I try to give some examples. JSON was designed for the web but now even used by VSCode to talk to Language Servers. A framework such as ASP.NET Web API can be easily self hosted in one process and consumed by another process. In your case, it is more suitable to start from analyzing the third party apps that you are going to support. Choose first what would be the transmission approach (sockets/named pipes/memory files), and then the framework to choose. Too many options.